# vectorize NumPy triple product on 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numpy-einsum

I am trying to vectorize the following triple product operation on an `N x N` array called `p` below:

```
for j in range(len(p)):
    for k in range(len(p)):
        for l in range(len(p)):
            h[j, k, l] = p[j, k] * p[k, l] * p[l, j] - p[j, l] * p[l, k] * p[k, j]
```

I thought `numpy.einsum` should be of use here, despite that I'm not actually summing over the repeated indices, but I haven't been able to pin it down. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply porting over those loop iterators as string notations, we would have an [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) based solution like so -

```
h = np.einsum('jk,kl,lj->jkl',p,p,p) - np.einsum('jl,lk,kj->jkl',p,p,p)
```

Being basically an expansion related question (as we are not reducing any axis), we can simply use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) too by introducing new axes with `None/np.newaxis` at various places for allowing the expansion, like so -

```
h = p[...,None]*p*p[:,None,:].T - p[:,None,:]*p.T*p.T[...,None]
```